# Search with additional words at the beginning

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I'd like to query rows from database that might start with any word from an alternation list. For instance, querying the name `blue tree house` would return records such as `the blue tree house` or `le blue tree house` or `A blue tree house`.

I attempted querying as follows:

```
SELECT NAME
FROM NAMES
WHERE (lower(names.name) ~ '^(no.?)*\s*\d*\s*\W*(an|the|le|leur|ils|a)?(blue)\W*\s*\y') AND
      (lower(names.name) ~ ' \yhouse ?\y')
```

[Here the Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=53f38381bdf02d5055d0dfc1c9c0bb7c) with additional examples and setup.

Comment: The rules are a bit unspecified: should that match the whole string or part of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the end of the string is invariable in each search pattern, I suggest to work with reversed names, so you can use a matching index efficiently:

```
CREATE INDEX ON names (lower(reverse(name)) COLLATE "C");
```

You may want to disallow trailing (and leading) spaces in `name`.

Then:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM   names
WHERE  lower(reverse(name)) LIKE lower(reverse('BLUE HOUSE')) || '%' -- backed by index
AND    name ~* '^((?:no\.?\s*)?\d*\y| a|an|the|le|leur|ils|a)\y';  -- filter the few remaining rows
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ad2b5516afa00a0e8d072e4d5dcd641b)*

See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

Is your "alternation list" complete? I added an expression to cover all examples you provided.

Noteworthy: `(?:no\.?\s*)?`

`(?:)` ... [capturing parentheses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-ATOMS-TABLE)
`\.` ... literal dot needs escaping backslash
`\s` ... [whitespace character](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CLASS-SHORTHAND-ESCAPES-TABLE)
`?` ... 0 or 1 times (like you had it, not required by examples)