# How to index a column for leading wildcard search and check progress?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, pattern-matching, pg-trgm

My table has 650M rows (according to a fast but decently precise estimate from a query I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/470749)).

It has a text column called `receiver_account_id`, and I need to be able to search those records like: `r.receiver_account_id LIKE '%otherWordsHere'`.

Because I'm using a leading wildcard, those searches are impossibly slow. I need an index. And my guess from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13452528/470749) is that I need a GIN index.

I ran:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY receipts_receiver_account_id_gin_idx ON public.receipts USING gin (receiver_account_id);
```

But I'm not sure that the index is even being created.

I [ran](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/249784/18098):

```
SELECT
  now()::TIME(0),
  a.query,
  p.phase,
  round(p.blocks_done / p.blocks_total::numeric * 100, 2) AS "% done",
  p.blocks_total,
  p.blocks_done,
  p.tuples_total,
  p.tuples_done,
  ai.schemaname,
  ai.relname,
  ai.indexrelname
FROM pg_stat_progress_create_index p
JOIN pg_stat_activity a ON p.pid = a.pid
LEFT JOIN pg_stat_all_indexes ai on ai.relid = p.relid AND ai.indexrelid = p.index_relid;
```

But I just see `<insufficient privilege>` (which is bizarre since I own this machine) and a bunch of `NULL`s.

The next 2 status queries I got from [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/242079/18098).

`SELECT * FROM pg_class, pg_index WHERE pg_index.indisvalid = false AND pg_index.indexrelid = pg_class.oid;` shows:

[image: screenshot1]

And then:

```
SELECT a.datname,
         l.relation::regclass,
         l.transactionid,
         l.mode,
         l.GRANTED,
         a.usename,
         a.query,
         a.query_start,
         age(now(), a.query_start) AS "age",
         a.pid
FROM pg_stat_activity a
JOIN pg_locks l ON l.pid = a.pid
WHERE mode = 'ShareUpdateExclusiveLock'
ORDER BY a.query_start;
```

Shows:
[image: screenshot2]

Am I doing this correctly? How can I know when the index creation will finish?

Comment: "which is bizarre since I own this machine"  PostgreSQL has no idea who has title to a piece of hardware.  It does know about its own role system, so you will have to describe how you are using that.

Comment: Please always declare your version of Postgres. And the (core!) table definition showing data types and constraints as `CREATE TABLE` script. Why did you choose to create the index `CONCURRENTLY`? Concurrent write load? Are queries with a leading wildcard the only (or the only important) kind of queries on that column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Tailored expression index

If queries with a leading wildcard are the only (or the only important) kind of queries on that column, then consider an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html), like @jjanes suggested. It's typically (much) smaller and cheaper to maintain than a trigram index, and faster for fitting queries. (It's far less versatile, though!)

In modern versions of Postgres I would lean towards a `COLLATE "C"` index instead of `text_pattern_ops`, though. See:

- [Is there a difference between text_pattern_ops and COLLATE "C"?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/291250/3684)

There is no indication in your question but, typically, you want to search case-insensitive. So I add `lower()` to the expression to arrive at:

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY receipts_receiver_account_id_rev_idx
ON public.receipts (lower(reverse(receiver_account_id)) COLLATE "C");
```

`CONCURRENTLY` only if you need to avoid an exclusive lock on the table. Else, it's faster without.

Match the expression in queries:

```
... WHERE lower(reverse(receiver_account_id))
     LIKE lower(reverse('otherWordsHere'   )) || '%' COLLATE "C";
```

Note how I concatenate the wildcard to the right explicitly. That allows Postgres to use the index even for generic query plans with parameterized *'otherWordsHere'*.

Or, faster yet, use the ["starts with" operator `^@`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) in **Postgres 15** or later:

```
... WHERE lower(reverse(receiver_account_id))
       ^@ lower(reverse('otherWordsHere'   )) COLLATE "C";
```

No wildcard. And no hurdles for generic query plans, either. See:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)

The minor downside of using `COLLATE "C"` instead of `text_pattern_ops` is that you have to spell out `COLLATE "C"` in queries to match the index. But while you have to match the "reverse" expression exactly anyway ...

Related:

- [Search with additional words at the beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62785415/search-with-additional-words-at-the-beginning/62785629#62785629)

If we know more about the `%` part and the `otherWordsHere` part in your pattern '%otherWordsHere', like length or constant bits, we might be able to optimize further.

#### Your failed attempt at a trigram index

You don't need the additional module `btree_gin` to create a trigram index on a string-type column. Just `pg_trgm`.
But you forgot to declare the needed operator class:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY receipts_receiver_account_id_gin_idx ON public.receipts
USING gin (receiver_account_id gin_trgm_ops);
```

You may still want that index to cover a variety of patterns ...

#### Escaping special characters in `LIKE` patterns

See:

- [Escape function for regular expression or LIKE patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144036/escape-function-for-regular-expression-or-like-patterns/45741630#45741630)

#### Tracking progress

> How can I know when the index creation will finish?

Since Postgres 12, you can consult [`pg_stat_progress_create_index`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/progress-reporting.html#CREATE-INDEX-PROGRESS-REPORTING) about progress. See:

- [Feedback on whether index was created on materialized views in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70252605/feedback-on-whether-index-was-created-on-materialized-views-in-postgresql/70252793#70252793)

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! I'm excited to dig into this. :-)

Comment: The project got sidelined suddenly so I still haven't looked into this, but it seems like it is probably really helpful, and I appreciate it! Accepted.

Comment: @Ryan: If you get to apply it eventually, I would love some feedback about which variant worked best for you.

Comment: I would surely revisit this answer and let you know! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A pg_trgm index can be used here, but it is unnecessarily slow and large.  Better would be a functional index.

```
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY receipts_receiver_account_id_rev_idx ON public.receipts (reverse(receiver_account_id) text_pattern_ops);

SELECT....WHERE reverse(r.receiver_account_id) LIKE reverse('%otherWordsHere')
```

If the pattern contained literal % or _ which are escaped by backslashes, then processing the pattern would need to more complex than just calling reverse() on it.